# Finding multivariable integral given only one bound?

Tags: probability, integration, multivariable-calculus

The pair (X, Y ) are distributed according to the joint density
$$f(x, y) = 2x(y − x)^2$$
for 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 and 0 ≤ y ≤ 2.

> a) Calculate P{Y ≤ 1}

Do I take than integral bounded like y ≤ 1 and 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 like 
$$\int_0^1 \left[\int_0^1 2x(y − x) dx\right]dy$$

which would result into some number. Or do I just integrate y ≤ 1, but treating x as some constant like

$$\int_0^1 2x(y − x) dy $$

this would result in an equation with x as the only variable.

> b) Calculate the marginal density of X

I have a feeling this has to do with something in the last problem? Like  if I was left with an equation from the last problem I would integrate it through again but with 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, so the result is a number.

Answer (score 1):

> > a) Calculate $P\{Y ≤ 1\}$
>
> Do I take than integral bounded like y ≤ 1 and 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 like
> $$\int_0^1 \left[\int_0^1 2x(y − x) dx\right]dy$$
> which would result into some number.

The probability measure is a constant, so that is what you should aim to produce.    Plus, those are indeed the bounds you require.

> > b) Calculate the marginal density of X
>
> I have a feeling this has to do with something in the last problem? Like  if I was left with an equation from the last problem I would integrate it through again but with 0 ≤ x ≤ 1, so the result is a number.

The marginal density is a monovariate function of $x$, so that is what you should aim to produce... "by integrating out the $y$", this time for the whole support.

$$f_X(x)~=~\int_0^2 2x(y − x) dy\quad\Big[0\leq x\leq 1\Big]$$

Answer (score 0):

(a) The entire premise is based on the fact that $$\iint_A f(x,y) dA=1.$$ You just need to change the integration bounds, like you suggest yourself in the first approach. The final probability has to be a constant, it cannot depend on $x$, so the second approach is clearly wrong. The first is the right one.

(b) The marginal density of $X$ can be computed by integrating out $Y$, i.e.$$f_X(x) = \int_{y=0}^{y=2} f(x,y) dA$$